# how can i set a state currency to APi currency

Tags: reactjs

please am I getting data from an API everything is okay, and I also have a state that stores the currency the user enters but I want to get whatever currency the store on the state. but am getting undefined. how can write the cde

Here's how the data look when I console it.

```
console.log(data.market_data.current_price)
{
aed: 6160.74,
ars: 323915,
aud: 2440.2,
bch: 11.046617,
bdt: 178256,
}
```

if I want to get a part data

```
console.log(data.market_data.current_price.bdt)
// output: 178256
```

but I have a state like this

```
const [currency, setCurrency] = useState("ars")
```

here's my code

```
console.log(data.market_data.current_price.currency)
```

but am getting undefined

Comment: `console.log(data.market_data.current_price[currency])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing an object property with a dynamically-computed name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/accessing-an-object-property-with-a-dynamically-computed-name)

Comment: am still getting undefined but getting the price is I specify the currency in a string  like this `console.log(data.market_data.current_price[`usd`]` but undefined like this `console.log(data.market_data.current_price[`${currency}`]`